# All users extensions on visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I manage PCs used by a lot of people who all need the same basic extensions.

Is it possible to install extensions for all users.
If so how can I do it?

thank's.

Comment: you can create an extension that is just a bundle (naming) of other extensions, the user only has to install 1 extension to get the complete list, the initial install can be done from a vsix file on the disk

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force-install extension in VSCode, you can use [VSCode command line interface](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions) to do that.

Do note however, that this extensions [will sync](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync) with user profile, if it is connected to Microsoft/GitHub.

[image: Vscode cli extensions page]

You also have the option of [suggesting the extensions](https://tattoocoder.com/recommending-vscode-extensions-within-your-open-source-projects) to users who open your repository.